# Which Linux distribution to use on 32 bit processor

Tags: linux, distribution-choice, 32bit

I have a Lenovo G580 model bought in year 2013. It has a 32 bit processor. I want to know which distribution of Linux will work perfectly on this machine.

Comment: If you're willing to hard way, I suggest gentoo, that way you can highly customize the OS, since your hardware is old.

Comment: I would suggest a distribution which is optimized for older hardware like Antix - https://antixlinux.com/

Comment: You can consider any distribution that offers a 32bit version. But without knowing the specifications of the system you've actually got it's not possible to offer specific advice. (At least some of the processors in that range were 64bit. Are you sure your is only 32bit?)

Comment: Are you really sure this is a 32-bit processor? I remember having bought a Lenovo laptop in 2014 and I'm pretty sure all the models on sale on Lenovo website were 64-bit processors (Intel Core i3 or i5, maybe 64-bit Pentium). What is your processor ?

Comment: CentOS 7 seems like a good option. The 8th version is only for x86_64

Comment: Specs I found say "CPU Intel Core i3 (3rd Gen) 3110M" which is 64 bit. You may have had 32 bit Windows, but most systems since about 2006 are 64 bit. Only a few tablet type systems were 64 bit with 32 bit UEFI. Your system also is probably UEFI.

Answer (score 1):

Depends quite a bit on what you want to do.

- **antiX**: good distribution, but relatively few pre-installed applications.
- **Linux Lite**: Good alternative, a lot of linux-lite specific applications, but uses `systemd`
- **Puppy Linux**: Probably the best usable distro for the extreme small computers.

There are others: Debian seems to support 32 bits, Slackware does,and quite a few more.